# Terminal line '-bash: :wq!: command not found' from start?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, command

Every time I enter my terminal the first lines follow:

[...] on ttys000
-bash: :wq!: command not found

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow! I've come a long way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:wq!` is the command to save the current file and exit from `vi`. You probably have an extraneous `:wq!` in your `.bashrc` from the last time it was edited.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have "wq!" in your bash profile or .profile which you may have added accidentally and need to remove.